# Error null exception in "for" construct xamarin android. Where is incorrect?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]This method returns the number of types of Views that will be created by getView method.

```html
public class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter{

  private  const int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
  private const int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

  private List<string> mData;
  private TreeSet sectionHeader;
 
  private LayoutInflater mInflater;

  public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<string> Data) {
   mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
   this.mData=Data;
  }

  public void addItem(string item) {
   mData.Add(item);
   NotifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public void addSectionHeaderItem(string item) {
   mData.Add(item);
   //sectionHeader.Add(mData.Count - 1);
   NotifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return sectionHeader.Contains(position) ? TYPE_SEPARATOR : TYPE_ITEM;
  }


  public int getViewTypeCount {
   get{ return 2; }
  }


  public override int Count {
   get {return mData.Count;}
  }


  public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position) {
   return mData[position];
  }
   
  public override long GetItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  } 

  public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder = null;
   int rowType = getItemViewType(position);

   if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    switch (rowType) {
    case TYPE_ITEM:
     convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewItemsSeparator, parent);
     holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewHeaderItems);
     break;
    case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
     convertView = mInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.textViewHeaderItems, parent);
     holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.textviewItemsSeparator);
     break;
    }
    convertView.Tag=holder;
   } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.Tag as ViewHolder;
   }
   holder.textView.Text=mData[position];

   return convertView;
  }

  public  class ViewHolder:Java.Lang.Object {
   public TextView textView;
  }

 }
```

```html
ListView lst;
  string[] items = new string[] { "Alternative Rock","Classical",...........};
  
  List<string> listItems;
  
  private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
  public override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);


   // Create your fragment here
  }

  public override View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
   // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);


   listItems = new List<string> (items);

   return inflater.Inflate (Resource.Layout.GenerFragment, container, false);
  }

  public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
   base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


   lst = View.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lstGenres);
 
   //lst.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.textViewHeaderItems,Resource.Id.textviewHeaderItems, items);
   //lst = View.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lst_genre);

   //lst.SetAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.Activity, Resource.Layout.GenerFragment, items));
   //mAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
   for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Count(); i++) {
    mAdapter.addItem (listItems[i]);
    if (i == 0) {
     mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem ("Music");
    } else if(i==13) {
     mAdapter.addSectionHeaderItem ("Audio");
    }
   }
   lst.Adapter = new CustomAdapter (Activity, listItems);
```

[image]

I spent much time for looking for errors but I have no idea why It was null. although It got a data from list

mAdapter.addItem (listItems[i]); -> null exception when I debug on device. Where is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

in `OnActivityCreated` you are referencing `listItems`

```
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Count(); i++) {
```

however, `listItems` is null.  You initialize it in `OnCreateView`, which has not been executed yet.  You need to be sure that `listItems` is initialized before you attempt to reference it.

Additionally, you are attempting to add items to mAdapter, but it's never been initialized (as far as I can see)

you declare it here, but it will be NULL until you initalize it

```
private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
```

here is the initialization, which is commented out

```
//mAdapter=new CustomAdapter();
```

when you attempt to reference it here, it is still null, and will throw a Null Reference Exception

```
mAdapter.addItem (listItems[i]);
```

Comment: I put listItems = new List<string> (items); in OnActiviityCreated .listItems is initialized but I still got that problem.

Comment: I try to put a text into add mAdapter.addItem (l"fsfas");. It still got that error

Comment: mAdapter is null also - you have the init line commented out

Comment: lst.Adapter = new CustomAdapter (Activity, listItems); this is init line

Comment: that doesn't initialize mAdapter.  See my additional notes

Comment: also, don't post code as screenshots.  It's not searchable and you can't copy/paste, it's a huge PITA for people trying to help you

Comment: one final comment - when an exception throws you into the debugger, you can hover over each line with the cursor and it will show you the value of each reference.  Use this to figure out which reference is NULL - this will help you debug your own errors faster

Comment: That your mean private CustomAdapter mAdapter; and mAdapter.addItem (listItems[i]);

Comment: I don't understant about here is the initialization, which is commented out

//mAdapter=new CustomAdapter();

Comment: Please read up on basic C# object references: https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/csharp

Comment: Cutomer there are two parameter

Comment: I understand about C# basic but I must new new CustomAdapter (Activity, listItems);

Comment: private CustomAdapter mAdapter;
mAdapter=new CustomAdapter (Activity, listItems);
That Your mean???

Comment: final comment: you have a for loop that builds mAdapter, but you never do anything with it after that.  What's it's purpose?  If you don't need it, just get rid of that code.  Why are you wasting time fixing a bug in code that you don't use?

Comment: It thrown null but my app is getting empty(lost toolbar,....). I was trying to create listview header. I spent three days to code. Results is nothing.